# Merge 2 elements together if the elements contains

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very messy data I am noticing patterns where ever there is '\n' end of the element, it needs to be merged with single element before that.

sample list:

```
ls = ['hello','world \n','my name','is john \n','How are you?','I am \n doing well']
ls
```

return/tryouts:

```
print([s for s in ls if "\n" in s[-1]])
>>>    ['world \n', 'is john \n'] # gave elements that ends with \n
```

How do I get it elements that ends with '\n' merge with 1 before element? Looking for a output like this one:

```
['hello world \n', 'my name is john \n', 'How are you?','I am \n doing well']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **reducing** a list, maybe, one **readable** approach is to use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html) function.

> functools.reduce(func, iter, [initial_value]) cumulatively performs an operation on all the iterable’s elements and, therefore, can’t be applied to infinite iterables.

First of all, you need a kind of struck to accumulate results, I use a tuple with two elements: **buffer with concatenated strings until I found "\n"** and **the list of results**. See *initial struct (1)*.

```
ls = ['hello','world \n','my name','is john \n','How are you?','I am \n doing well']

def combine(x,y):
    if y.endswith('\n'):
        return ( "", x[1]+[x[0]+" "+y] )  #<-- buffer to list
    else:
        return ( x[0]+" "+y, x[1] )       #<-- on buffer

t=reduce( combine, ls, ("",[]) ) #<-- see initial struct (1)
t[1]+[t[0]] if t[0] else t[1] #<-- add buffer if not empty
```

**Result**:

```
['hello world \n', 'my name is john \n', 'How are you? ', 'I am \n doing well ']
```

(1) Explained initial struct: you use a tuple to store buffer string until `\n` and a list of already cooked strings:

```
("",[])
```

Means:

```
("__ buffer string not yet added to list __", [ __result list ___ ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this out so it is simple to understand instead of trying to make it more complex as a list comprehension.

This will work for any number of words until you hit a `\n` character and clean up the remainder of your input as well.

```py
ls_out = []            # your outgoing ls
out = ''               # keeps your words to use
for i in range(0, len(ls)):
    if '\n' in ls[i]:   # check for the ending word, if so, add it to output and reset
        out += ls[i]
        ls_out.append(out)
        out = ''
    else:                # otherwise add to your current word list
        out += ls[i]
if out:   # check for remaining words in out if total ls doesn't end with \n
    ls_out.append(out)
```

You may need to add spaces when you string concatenate but I am guessing that it is just with your example.  If you do, make this edit:

```py
        out += ' ' + ls[i]
```

**Edit:**
If you want to only grab the one before and not multiple before, you could do this:

```py
ls_out = []
for i in range(0, len(ls)):
    if ls[i].endswith('\n'):             # check ending only
        if not ls[i-1].endswith('\n'):   # check previous string
            out = ls[i-1] + ' ' + ls[i]  # concatenate together
        else:
            out = ls[i]                  # this one does, previous didn't
    elif ls[i+1].endswith('\n'):         # next one will grab this so skip
        continue
    else:
        out = ls[i]                      # next one won't so add this one in
    ls_out.append(out)
```

Comment: something is not working well and missing one element:   ['helloworld \n', 'my nameis john \n', 'How are you?I am \n doing well']

Comment: I added a comment at the bottom.  I am assuming that just in their example text they don't have outer spaces but in their actual usage the spaces are probably not being stripped.  If they are being stripped, you can change the string concatenation to add the space.

Comment: No. I mean you cannot do this:  out += ls[i]...  It will concat element 3 and 4 thus you are missing one element of the result. The output requires 4 items and you have only 3 items.

Comment: Yes correct, I explained that up top that it will work for any number until you hit an ending `\n` character. I'll add an alternative to not do that if they don't want to.

Comment: why are you submitting your solution if it has INCORRECT output?

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb Thanks so much! Learned some more functions from here. I used `out += ' ' + ls[i]` for my case from your suggestion

Comment: No problem sharp. @daniherrera I voted on your answer but I would guess that it is based on simplicity to read and understand.

Comment: hi @MyNameIsCaleb, you are so kind. "Simplicity and readability" are the main reasons because is hard to understand to me he/she chose this approach. `reduce` is simple and readable. Any case, thanks about your up-vote.

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks guys for pointing it out to me. I am bit new with list comprehension. I tried both of the solution and I found both of them very helpful and working. Unfortunately, I can't except both answers on stack. For my condition, using 'reduce' helped as well after pointing out how simple it is ...going to accept 'reduce'. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using the regex expression using the 're' module.

```
import re
ls = ['hello','world \n','my name','is john \n','How are you?','I am \n doing well']
new_ls = []
for i in range(len(ls)):
    concat_word = ''                # reset the concat word to ''
    if re.search(r"\n$", str(ls[i])):      # matching the \n at the end of the word
        try:
            concat_word = str(ls[i-1]) + ' ' + str(ls[i])  # appending to the previous word
        except:
            concat_word = str(ls[i])     # in case if the first word in the list has \n
        new_ls.append(concat_word)
    elif re.search(r'\n',str(ls[i])):      # matching the \n anywhere in the word
        concat_word = str(ls[i])  
        new_ls.extend([str(ls[i-1]), concat_word])   # keeps the word before the "anywhere" match separate
print(new_ls)
```

This returns the output

```
['hello world \n', 'my name is john \n', 'How are you?', 'I am \n doing well']
```

Comment: Yes. I just want it merge with previous element if \n is the element. I dont need to join 'I am \n doing well'. Since \n is somewhere in middle not end. The ouput that I posted on the question is what I am looking for? Is it possible to do?

Comment: I have tweaked my code according to your request. Let me know what you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first element doesn't end with `\n` and all words are longer than 2 characters:

```
res = []
for el in ls:
  if el[-2:] == "\n":
    res[-1] = res[-1] + el
  else:
    res.append(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst=[]
for i in range(len(ls)):
    if "\n" in ls[i][-1]:
        lst.append((ls[i-1] + ' ' + ls[i]))
        lst.remove(ls[i-1])
    else:
        lst.append(ls[i])
lst
```

Result:

```
['hello world \n', 'my name is john \n', 'How are you?', 'I am \n doing well']
```